# How to Play Audio File on Android ICS 4.0.3 and 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

```
_mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mysound);
_mediaPlayer.start();
```

It works on Android 1.6 or 2.1 or 2.2 or 2.3.3 but, when I updated from 4.0.1 to 4.0.4 then doesnt work!

Any ideas?

Comment: The question contains too little information. You should at the very least post some logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must do this in AsyncTask class, not in main threat